# How to convert string, integer, dates, etc into queryable format in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a ruby gem. One of the functions of that gem is to execute insert query on the database based on the data_rows that the user provide. I need to make insert query using those data rows. Now those data rows may have string, integer, dates, etc. into them. So I need to convert them into appropriate format for the query(like "string" to "\"string\"", ) I need to know if there is any gem that can make my life easier?

Right now I am trying to convert them into based on their type. So if it is a string first I thought I can do like

```
def formatted_value(val)
   (val.is_a? String) ? "\"#{val}\"" : val
end
```

So if val is `"some text"` it will just return `"\"some text\""` and I can go ahead and use it like

```
"Insert into table (str) VALUES (#{formatted_value(val)})"
=> "Insert into table (str) VALUES (\"some Text\")"
```

Which I can send to mysql client. But that again have some complications. For example, if the user sends val to be `"some \"Text\""` I want to convert it to be like `"\"some \\\"Text\\\" \""` so that the query becomes

```
"Insert into table (str) VALUES (\"some \\\"Text\\\" \") "
```

before sending it to mysql client.One thing that I can do here is escape string but then again I don't know if it is already escaped or not.

Also, that is just for string I need to handle date conversion to string too as by to_s conversion doesn't fit the format. 
That's why I want to know if there is anything already available for these.

Comment: Did you consider to use sql parameters for the query?

Comment: "I need to know if there is any gem that can make my life easier?" That makes your question off-topic. Instead, you need to do your research, decide on what you like, work with it, then ask a question. Asking us to recommend something is off-topic.

Comment: @theTinMan I tried to look for it but didn't get something which exactly fits the requirement. Thanks anyway for encouraging someone new to the platform for asking a question. -_-
Also, the question was not just about the availability of gem. I thought someone experienced might suggest some alternative approach.

Comment: @FabioI am not very clear about how to use SQL parameters for the query. I just got the parameters in form of data_rows then I am trying to push them into the string to make a query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) describes itself as a 'Database Toolkit for Ruby'. It can be used to construct and execute SQL queries for various database vendors. It handles value coercion for you. For example:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect('jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db')

DB[:table].insert(str: 'some Text')
# INSERT INTO "table" ("str") VALUES ('some Text') RETURNING "id"

DB[:table].insert(str: "some \"Text\"")
# INSERT INTO "table" ("str") VALUES ('some "Text"') RETURNING "id"

DB[:table].insert(str: 1)
# INSERT INTO "table" ("str") VALUES (1) RETURNING "id"

DB[:table].insert(str: Date.new(2000, 1, 1))
# INSERT INTO "table" ("str") VALUES ('2000-01-01') RETURNING "id"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/a8flci/ruby_mysql2_gem_sql_injection/
A good source that mentions two methods. One using Sequel gem and other using Mysql2 gem prepare then execute.